# Configuring Caps Lock as modifier and layout switcher

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, awesome, xkb

I want to set the caps lock key working as a modifier (modkey) and layout switcher at the same time.

- I want Caps Lock to act as a modkey in awesome in different hotkey combinations, for example, Caps Lock + Enter opens terminal and so on.
- When Caps Lock is pressed as a single key, it should act as a layout switcher on its release (by calling function that executes setxkbmap in rc.lua config).

How can I accomplish that?

I tried to turn Caps Lock into a modkey, but `modkey = "Lock"` in rc.lua does not seem to work right now, and after I finally made it work somehow (with xmodmap or changing the latter line in config), modkey was acting exactly the way Caps Lock acts: one press turnes it on, and another turns it off.
Even if I make Caps Lock the modkey instead of Super_L, I still have no idea of how to handle its single-key release.

Comment: I managed to get Caps Lock working to switch layouts: `os.execute("setxkbmap -layout 'us,ru' -variant 'colemak,' -option 'grp:caps_toggle,grp_led:caps'")`. I still don't know how to combine its functions of modifier and layout switcher.